# Pandas: Filter in rows that have a Null/None/NaN value in any of several specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a csv file which has a lot of strings called `"NULL"` in it, in several columns.

I would like to select (filter in) rows that have a `"NULL"` value in *any* of *several specific* columns.

Example:

> ```
> ["Firstname"]   ["Lastname"]    ["Profession"]
> "Jeff"          "Goldblum"      "NULL"
> "NULL"          "Coltrane"      "Musician"
> "Richard"       "NULL"          "Physicist"
> ```

Here, I would like to filter in (select) rows in `df` that have the value `"NULL"` in the column `"Firstname"` *or* `"Lastname"` – but not if the value is `"NULL"` in `"Profession"`.

This manages to filter in strings (not `None`) in one column:

```
df = df[df["Firstname"].str.contains("NULL", case=False)]
```

I have however attempted to convert the `"NULL"` strings to `None` via:

```
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

Given the above `str.contains` filtering, perhaps it's easier to filter in `"NULL"` strings before converting to `None`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need first [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `NULL` string to `NaN`. Then check all `NaN` values in selected columns by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) and select all rows where is [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) `True` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.replace("NULL", np.nan)

print (df[['Firstname','Lastname']].isnull())
  Firstname Lastname
0     False    False
1      True    False
2     False     True

print (df[df[['Firstname','Lastname']].isnull().any(1)])
  Firstname  Lastname Profession
1       NaN  Coltrane   Musician
2   Richard       NaN  Physicist
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
df.replace(to_replace="NULL", value = None)
```

to replace all the occurence of `"NULL"` to `None`